# Deploying to specifc AWS ec2 instance from Visual Studio

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In my visual studio project, I have downloaded the AWS extension and I am able to publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance without any issue. This was good for testing.

What I am struggling to do is deploying to an existing instance (aka, one that wasn't created via elastic beanstalk tool in VS) in my AWS console.

Everywhere I look I only find ways to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk from the Visual Studio but I can't find an option to deploy to another instance.

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: What do you mean by "another instance"? Do you mean another EB environment?

Comment: It will be handled automatic by Elastic beanstalk. For example, if you have 3 active instances running against a single elasticbeanstalk and if you deploy a new version of your project, it will be deployed to all the active instances.

Comment: @Marcin in AWS console under EC2 you see Running Instances. Through VS I am able to use the AWS tool to create an elastic beanstalk instance (which automatically gets added to the running instances in AWS console), however I want my code to deploy to an existing instance that was not created through elastic beanstalk

Comment: @JijoCleetus but only one instance is for the elastic beanstalk. The instance I want to deploy to wasn't built by elastic beanstalk. Basically I am trying to update an old instance that's been sitting idle for a couple of years (which again was not created using VS elastic beanstalk)

Answer (score 0):

For automated deployments to instances [AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html) is generally used. It could be setup with [AWS CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/index.html) as well.

The benefit of using both CD and CP is that CP can detect changes to your source code and trigger automated deployments using CD to a single instance or a fleet of instances.

I can't comment on the use in VS, but this is how it is normally done. Thus its possible  that VS also supports architectures based on CD and CP. Even if not, you could setup automated trigger of CP based on the source code changes. This would work whether or not VS directly supports them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question wasn't regarding automated deployments. If I want to do a manual deployment i.e. I have a folder of code files and DLLs that I want to transfer to the instance, how do I do that? SSH?

Comment: @joeyeds [scp](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/scp/) would be easiest to use if posssible. `rsync` can also copy files over ssh.